# MySQL Stored procedure IN parameter issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In my Mysql , I have written below stored procedure to insert data into user table,

DELIMITER $$

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CreateUser1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateUser1`(
    IN Email VARCHAR(50),
    IN Password1 VARCHAR(50),
    IN FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    IN LastName VARCHAR(50),
    IN AlternateEmail VARCHAR(50),
    IN PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50),
    IN Token VARCHAR(500)
)

BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT user_id FROM `um.user` WHERE `email`=Email)THEN   
        INSERT INTO `um.user`(site_id,email,PASSWORD,alternate_email,first_name,last_name,contact_number,
                    created_on,updated_on,is_active,token,is_verified_email)
        VALUES
        (1, Email1 , Password1 ,AlternateEmail,  FirstName , LastName ,PhoneNumber,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),UTC_TIMESTAMP(),1,Token,0);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i test this procedure as below,

```
CALL `CreateUser1`('ab1@ansys.com' , 'abcdefgh' ,'abc@gmail.com',  'sa' , '' ,'123456789','hasghsdfhgfhgfhdgfhdsgsh');

SELECT * FROM `um.user` WHERE email='ab1@ansys.com';
```

It does nothing.

It doesn't insert data into table, I figured out the issue .

The isssue is in parameter "Email".

But when I change the parameter "Email" to "Email12" , it worked as expected.

But I don't want to change in parameter as it will be a change in my API as well,

Now i want to solve this issue in sp level as well, I have tried below changes as well in SP which also doesn't works,

```
Set @userEmail=Email;
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT user_id FROM `um.user` WHERE `email`=@userEmail)THEN
```

Any suggestions

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: Shouldn't it be called with:  
CALL `CreateUser1`('ab1@ansys.com' , 'abcdefgh' ,  'sa' , '','abc@gmail.com' ,'123456789','hasghsdfhgfhgfhdgfhdsgsh');  (the AlternateEmail is after LastName not before FirstName)

Comment: In MySQL, the parameter name passed to a Stored Procedure should not be the same as Column Name. I got this issue long ago and found out this is the reason.

Comment: The procedure will not throw any error, but they are not equivalent. You will have different data in the table

Comment: Avoid naming your variables and parameters with a name equal to the columns of your tables. Check [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also qualify their identifiers. See [9.2.1 Identifier Qualifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

```sql
...
               /*
               -- You can also use Alias    
               SELECT `user_id`
               FROM `um.user` `uu`
               WHERE `uu`.`email` = `Email`
               */
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `user_id`
               FROM `um.user`
               WHERE `um.user`.`email` = `Email`) THEN
...
```

- [SQL Fiddle demo unqualified](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d7d2/1)
- [SQL Fiddle demo qualified](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fed26/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to handle your issue within the stored procedure itself, without changing the name of parameter,

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CreateUser1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateUser1`(
    IN Email VARCHAR(50),
    IN Password1 VARCHAR(50),
    IN FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    IN LastName VARCHAR(50),
    IN AlternateEmail VARCHAR(50),
    IN PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50),
    IN Token VARCHAR(500)
)

BEGIN
    DECLARE Email1 VARCHAR(50);
    SET Email1 = Email;
    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT user_id FROM `um.user` WHERE `email`=Email1)THEN   
        INSERT INTO `um.user`(site_id,email,PASSWORD,alternate_email,first_name,last_name,contact_number,
                    created_on,updated_on,is_active,token,is_verified_email)
        VALUES
        (1, Email1 , Password1 ,AlternateEmail,  FirstName , LastName ,PhoneNumber,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),UTC_TIMESTAMP(),1,Token,0);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is because in MySQL, the parameter name passed to a Stored Procedure should not be the same as Column Name. Hope this solves your problem :)